# Is Recyclerview is best for different List Item View

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview

Currently, I am having a `ListView` with different list item view for each row (Most cases Different).
I am having 6 different item layout, I will add more in future, and I will have only like 5-15 list items, some time may be less and may be many in other cases.

Some item views contains:

- ViewPager
- ListViews
- ImageViews
- Texviews
- Gridviews
- CAROUSEL
- Webviews

As this is dynamically generated depends on data, I am facing following issues :

- Scrolling Slowly (Some Times)
- List Item height
- Performance

Is `RecyclerView` the best solution in this case?

Comment: Wow, are you putting all that stuff in items of a list?

Comment: @Joffrey
Yea,
I can't make and xml for that (Because it dynamically loaded from web service)
For that i need an adapter,First i tried https://github.com/frankiesardo/LinearListView
It sucks in many places 
so i done with Listview ,but now i have performance issues,
Can you tell me best way to do it 
Thanks

Comment: I was more commenting on the kind of UI that would produce, rather than the performance aspect. Doesn't it look weird? Do you have a screenshot (out of curiosity)? If you want a scrollable list of items, then IMO the `ListView` is the way to go, with a well designed adapter using multiple view types. If this causes performance issues then maybe the recycling is not managed properly.

Comment: Your other option would be to dynamically add elements to a `LinearLayout`, but if you have 15 items, it might be worse in terms of performance.

Comment: How can you have a `ListView` within an item of a `ListView`? How is the user supposed to interact with that?

Comment: @Joffrey Listview inside Listview i will set height of inner listview to max so Scroll is not any issue any more,

Comment: Mmmh ok, but it sounds really weird to me. Since there will be no scroll on the inner `ListView`, is it really appropriate in the firts place? Also, your layout seems very complicated, I'm just wondering how users would deal with it.

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing your code to identify specific concerns, it's hard to address specific reasons why you are seeing such performance problems. Such as, are you properly using the [ViewHolder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21501329/1243753) paradigm? Or are you inappropriately loading stuff on the UI thread when it should be loaded on a background thread? Android has a small section talking about [scrolling smoothly](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html) with a ListView you should check out.  That aside,based on what you have mentioned so far...I think you major problem is design.

**Problems**

1. If your `ViewPager` is using a  `FragmentPagerAdapter`...then that will definitely be causing a lot of overhead and performance drag.
2. `ListView`: You should never ever place a `ListView` within another `ListView`. This will cause all sorts of problems. Android does not like [embedding two scrollable widgets](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3495890/1243753) that scroll the same direction. Even if this worked, it'll cause some major performance problems.
3. `GridView`: Same goes with the `GridView`.  You should never ever place a `GridView` within another `ListView`. Even if this worked, it'll cause some major performance problems.
4. If you're `ImageView` is loading some large graphics, it should be on a background thread and not the UI thread.  Else you'll get some slow performance
5. Carousel - I have no idea what API this is but if it scrolls vertically, then it's a no go.
6. `WebViews` are a very heavy weight object. I can definitely see this guy slowing things down, especially if it's loading a lot of content.

To build off what @Joffrey has said. There are some major concerns in your choice of UI. Based on what you are placing in this `ListView` tells me that you need to seriously rethink how to display your content to the user. Eg, try using a `TableLayout` or `GridLayout` instead of a `GridView`.