# List view Scrolling

Tags: android, listview

I have `ListView` filling It with an `Adapter` , I scroll in the `ListView` to view the next items, when I return to the items on the top of the list, I found that the data at the top is different than the first time `ListView` is initialized. I fill list using Api called From Server.

Comment: the problem is in getview method. post here code to identify problem

Comment: Thanks alot  " Hitesh Gehlot " your advice help me to solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

it's may help full to you.

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {

return getCount();

}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {

return position;

}

Answer (score 0):

```
    if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_row_myappointments, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

//your fields like below:

            holder.userName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.username);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
```

Try to change code like this in your getView()

Answer (score 0):

> Have you used ViewHolder to hold view in its position? If not then use
>   it.

Here is the useful link:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21501329/7391385

If you want full demo then try this:

https://dzone.com/articles/optimizing-your-listview