# Make ListView Scroll Smoothly

Tags: android, list, listview, android-asynctask

I have the following code to load my ListView (Each Item Has an Image and Text):

```
public View getView(final int i, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contact_inflater, null);
    final Holder holder = new ContactAdapter.Holder();

    holder.ivPhoto = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ivImage);
    holder.tvFullName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
    holder.tvPhoneNumber = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvPhoneNo);
    holder.tvFullName.setText(Contact.get(i).get(0));
    holder.tvPhoneNumber.setText(Contact.get(i).get(1));
    holder.button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.ivButton);
        
    Picasso.with(context)
                .load(Contact.get(i).get(2))
                .into(holder.ivPhoto);
    
    return view;
}
```

The problem is the list isn't scrolling smoothly. How do I make it smooth?

***EDIT:*** I have changed to RecycleView but I forgot to add the following code:

```
if(//IF//){ 
    Log.d("InInIn!", "InInIn!"); 
    
    //Turn to Tagged
}
```

When I turn it into a RecycleView, The button turns Tagged all over the pace and the tagged buttons change as a scroll. The buttons are changing all over the place even though they shouldn't. Whats the issue?

Comment: AFAIK, picasso will load the images asynchronously. The problem with scrolling here is not picasso. It's the lack of [viewholder pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21501316/what-is-the-benefit-of-viewholder) in your getView implementation

Comment: How do I fix my viewholder pattern?

Comment: Use RecyclerView instead

Comment: Im a beginner, How do I change to recyclerView?

Comment: You don't *need* to use a RecyclerView, but you do at least need to change your ViewHolder code. The point of the ViewHolder is to not have to call `findViewById` every time (see https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling and https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/09/android-viewholder-pattern-example.html). Picasso load may also be an issue though. You should profile it to see what's being slow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `recyclerView` instead. It is a more advanced and flexible version of ListView. Go through https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview for guide.

If you want to stick with ListView then in order to improve the performance you should recycle/reuse the views that are no longer visible to the user.

```
public View getView(final int i, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
       
    Holder holder = null;
    if(convertView == null){
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contact_inflater, null);
        final Holder holder = new ContactAdapter.Holder();
        holder.ivPhoto = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivImage);
        holder.tvFullName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
        holder.tvPhoneNumber = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvPhoneNo);
        holder.button = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivButton);
        convertView.setTag(holder)
    }
    else{
        holder = (Holder)convertView.getTag()
    } 

    holder.tvFullName.setText(Contact.get(i).get(0));
    holder.tvPhoneNumber.setText(Contact.get(i).get(1));

    Picasso.with(context)
                .load(Contact.get(i).get(2))
                .into(holder.ivPhoto);

    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: This helped except for one issue.

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: I will edit the code but change the button if the phonenumber equals something. If I do this above, The button changes all over the place even though it shouldn;t.

Comment: I got your problem, try this: holder.tvFullName.setText(Contact.get(i).get(0));
        holder.tvPhoneNumber.setText(Contact.get(i).get(1)); After this add your if-else for button change.

Comment: What is the difference?

Comment: I have edited my comment. What exactly you want to do with the button?

Comment: You will have to provide an else for your if condition. if(postitons.contains(Contact.get(i).get(1))){...} else{holder.button.setText("whatever you want")}

Answer (score 0):

You can debug and check what recived to Picasso, you add: un listener for watch the error

```
        .into(ontact.get(i).get(2), new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Exception e) {
            }
        })
```

Comment: Picasso is not the issue?

Comment: you check the documentation and show the error in debugger, i don't know what's the problem if don't show me the code when receive the data

Answer (score 0):

```
public View getView(final int i, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    Holder holder;
    if(null == convertView){
        holder = new ContactAdapter.Holder();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contact_inflater, null);
        holder.ivPhoto = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ivImage);
        holder.tvFullName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
        holder.tvPhoneNumber = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvPhoneNo);
        holder.button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.ivButton);
        converView.setTag(holder);
    }else{
        holder = (Holder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    holder.tvFullName.setText(Contact.get(i).get(0));
    holder.tvPhoneNumber.setText(get(i).get(1));
    Picasso.with(context)
                    .load(Contact.get(i).get(2))
                    .into(holder.ivPhoto);
    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use Databinding in your list adapter and get layout components without using findViewById in your getView method.

Answer (score 0):

**try this:**

This is the new and updated getView scroll faster

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup paramViewGroup) {
    Object current_event = mObjects.get(position);
    ViewHolder holder = null;

    if (convertView == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_event, null);
        holder.ThreeDimension = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ThreeDim);
        holder.EventPoster = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.EventPoster);
        // This will now execute only for the first time of each row
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams imageParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(measuredwidth, rowHeight);
        holder.EventPoster.setLayoutParams(imageParams);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    // This way you can simply avoid conditions
    holder.ThreeDimension.setVisibility(object.getVisibility());

    return convertView;
}
```